# How to decalare DOMMatrix and WebKitCSSMatrix in Typescript?

Tags: typescript

When I try to access `window.DOMMatrix` or `window.WebKitCSSMatrix` in Typescript (3.3.3), I get the error:

> Property 'DOMMatrix' does not exist on type 'Window'.

So I tried declaring them on the window object, e.g.,

```js
interface MatrixWindow extends Window {
  DOMMatrix?: DOMMatrix;
  WebKitCSSMatrix?: DOMMatrix;
}
declare let window: MatrixWindow;
```

Then when I do `new window.DOMMatrix(transform)`, I get the error:

> Cannot use 'new' with an expression whose type lacks a call or construct signature.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out how to type a variable as a class that becomes the desired type after instantiation. This worked:

```js
interface MatrixWindow extends Window {
  DOMMatrix?: new (init: string | number[]) => DOMMatrix;
  WebKitCSSMatrix?: new (init: string | number[]) => DOMMatrix;
}
declare let window: MatrixWindow;
```

(#rubberducking)